# How can I edit top status bar at AppleWatch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I'm beginning with WatchKit and I would like to know hoy to edit the aspect of topbar in a AppleWatch app. I would like to change the color and also to hide it in some of my views because I want to focus my user to perform one action.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to edit the status bar appearance. There are some strong restrictions:

- Status bar cannot be hidden
- There are not ability to modify the black background
- You cannot add or modify the back button or another image

The only thing you can do is to change the title color using tint color in your storyboard and the text both of through storyboard and source code.

**Change color**

[image]

**Change text**

```
[self setTitle:@"MyTitle"];
```

Comment: Mmmm, not at this moment. I think they are still developing the WatchKit SDK and if you have any suggestion you can propose it through their bugs report bugreport.apple.com ;)

Comment: @EnriMR can we set title in center ?

Comment: A real shame we are stuck with a black bar.