# Apple Watch - how to change the background color in navigation

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

Can we change the color in navigation from black to the color white?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API to change the navigation bar's background colour right now. Ideally, your app's background colour would also be black. Check out the HIG for details: https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. And Apple recommend developers to use black background color.

I answered some days ago here [How can I edit top status bar at AppleWatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967601/how-can-i-edit-top-status-bar-at-applewatch/29967735#29967735)

It is impossible to edit the status bar appearance. There are some strong restrictions:

- Status bar cannot be hidden
- There are not ability to modify the black background
- You cannot add or modify the back button or another image

The only thing you can do is to change the title color using tint color in your storyboard and the text both of through storyboard and source code.