# How Do I Change NavigationBar Color For WatchOS?

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, watchos

I am building watchOS app and I am trying to change navigationBar background color from black to transparent, but I am not able to find anything. I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097023/apple-watch-how-to-change-the-background-color-in-navigation) which was asked in 2015, according to which it is impossible to change navigationBar color in watchOS. I was wondering if now there is any API for that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NavigationBarTitle color change for watchOS in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035341/navigationbartitle-color-change-for-watchos-in-swiftui)

Comment: @Luuk, I need to change background color of navigationBar, not title.

Answer (score 1):

This is about [Color](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/color/) in the human-interface-guidelines from apple:

> Make sure your app’s colors work well in both light and dark
> appearance modes. **With the exception of watchOS, which always uses a
> pure black background**, the platforms offer a dark alternative to the
> default light appearance. Dark Mode uses a darker color palette for
> all screens, views, menus, and controls, and can increase vibrancy — a
> subtle effect that dynamically blends foreground and background colors
> — to make foreground content stand out against darker backgrounds.
> System colors automatically support both appearances; if you use a
> custom color, you need to supply both light and dark variants. For
> guidance, see Dark Mode.

Comment: Okay, so can i use custom color for my navigationBar in watchOS? If yes, how?